# JavaFX - Need help seting Stage upon initialize

Tags: java, javafx, stage

I keep getting a `null` reference exception when I try to set my stage to a variable upon initialization.

my code.

```
public class ListController implements Initializable {
        private Stage thisStage;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            lblCount.setText("Hey"); //This works

            thisStage = (Stage) lblCount.getScene().getWindow(); //this doesn't
        }

        public ListController()
        {
            thisStage = (Stage) lblCount.getScene().getWindow(); //this doesn't
        }
}
```

I tried to use a constructor and that didn't work neither.

Comment: Where has lblCount been initialized?

Comment: @BenWin The first issue to be resolved is the null reference issue.

Comment: At the time the controller's `initialize()` method is called, the UI represented by the FXML file hasn't been added to a `Scene`. So `lblCount().getScene()` evaluates to `null` here, and you get a `NullPointerException`. What are you actually trying to do with the window?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is just to have a reference of the actual stage/window. so If I ever want to manipulate the stage i could do. thisStage.hide() or thisStage.bringtofront() or something like that. I didn't want to have to do lblCont.getScene().getWindow().hide() everytime I wanted to interact with the stage. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get a reference to the stage is to create a method on your controller and set it:

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent node = loader.load(getClass().getResource("view.fxml").openStream());
        Scene scene = new Scene(node);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Controller controller = (Controller)loader.getController();

        controller.setPrimaryStage(stage);

        stage.show();
```

Then in your method you have a valid reference.

Comment: I'd opt for this, too, if I ever had to. Define a common `BaseController` class for all your JavaFX controllers, let it have a property `primaryStage` (of type `Window` or `Stage`) and provide setter/getter as needed.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the stage ya can pass the stage reference by a method like this

```
  Stage primaryStage = new Stage(); 
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
  loader.setLocation(YourClass.class.getResource("yourpaht.fxml"));
  //here you change AnchorPane for your root Node
  rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
  // Show scene.
  Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  // Da acceso al programa principal.
  ListController controller = loader.getController();
  //method for passing the stage to the controller 
  controller.controlerPassing(this, primaryStage);
  // Show stage,
  primaryStage.show();
```

now the controler class looks can  look like something like this

```
public class ListController implements Initializable {
      private Stage stage;
      pivate YourClass classs;

      public controlerPassing(YourClass classs, Stage stage){
        this.stage = stage;
        this.classs = classs;
      }

     @Override
     public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
          lblCount.setText("Hey"); //This works
          //now you can do whatever you want whit the stage
          stage. do stuff........
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This null reference can be solved if we find out the data types in the Stage class and use such initialization accordingly.

For example,

```
Stage myStage = null ; // this will raise a null pointer reference exception the possible solution can be to say:

Stage myStage = {" ", 0, ' ', etc } ; // as long as the class Stage has data members like String, int, char, etc
```